# Is it posible to use ajax respone outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, global-variables

Any way of using the `data_response` outside the `$.post()`?

This is part of the code I use:

```
$.post('do.php', { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
    function(data_response){
        var response = data_response; //I need to access this variable outside of $.post()
    }
}, "json");

console.log(response); //response is not defined, is what I get for now
```

### UPDATE

Is there no way of getting that response available globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; `$.post` executes asynchronously, so when you call `console.log`, the AJAX request is still running and hasn't yet yielded a response. This is the purpose of the callback function: to provide code to be run *after* the request has completed. If you move `console.log` into the callback function, it should work:

```
$.post('do.php', { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
    function(data_response){
        var response = data_response; //I need to access this variable outside of $.post()
        console.log(response);
    }
}, "json");
```

---

**Update:** If you want the response data to be globally available, you can declare the variable in the global scope like so:

```
var response = null;
$.post('do.php', { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
    function(data_response){
        response = data_response;
        console.log(response);
    }
}, "json");
```

Of course, the only context in which you can be sure that `response` has
actually been populated with a value is in the callback function supplied to
`$.post` after the line `response = data_response;`. If you want to use it at
any other stage in the script then you'll have to check its value first;
something like this:

```
if (response !== null)
{
    console.log(response);
}
```

Just be aware that this code won't do anything if you put it straight after
the `$.post` call; it'll only be useful if it's executed after the POST request has finished, in some other asynchronous callback (perhaps a UI interaction event of some kind).

Comment: is there no way of getting that response available globally?

Comment: @w0rldart: You can assign it to a globally scoped variable, but you need to be careful about when it's actually populated. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variable outside of the callback so it is scoped to a part of the code that you can reach it from:

```
var response;

$.post('do.php', { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
    function(data_response){
    response = data_response; 
    }
}, "json");

console.log(response); //response is now defined - It won't be populated yet though.
```

As pointed out in the code above, although response will be defined, it won't be populated by the time you call console.log, however if you access the variable at some point after the callback has fired, it will be populated.

If you go down this route, you probably want to make use of a module pattern or closure to avoid putting the response variable in the global scope (you probably want to do this anyway in fairness)

Crockford's Module pattern: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Comment: nope, the _only_ reasonable way to fix the OPs problem is to use the value either _in_ the callback, or in the chain of functions called by the callback.  Just "hoping" that at some point the variable will be populated is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: To be fair I think the question is really about scoping of variables - What you do with that variable is outside the scope of the question. Obviously it's not going to be populated until the call back has fired.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a a variable, and check for done() anywhere in your script, if it's done it will execute immediately, if not it will execute once the ajax call is done.

```
var XHR = $.post('do.php', { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
    function(data_response){
        // do somehing with data_response
    }
}, "json");


function doSomethingElse() {
    XHR.done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the response outside of $.post() and you need to be sure that this value is populated right after the $.post() call you could try to make the "POST" call in a synchronous manner. This cannot be made with $.post() but cand be made using $.ajax():

```
var returnedData = null;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'do.php', 
  data: { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
  success: function (response) {
            returnedData = response;
        },
  dataType: "text"
});

console.log(returnedData );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```
var returnedData = {}; //Declaring Object var not just var
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'do.php',
data: { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id },
success: function (response) {
returnedData.result1=response;  //Add response into the Object created outside the ajax
},
dataType: "json"
});
console.log(returnedData);//inside it you can get returnedData.result1
```